# Is there a way to check if a role exists by its ID discord.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm making a command with which you can set a warned role for your server. I've run into a problem that it would set the warned role to whatever value you give as an argument of the command. I want it to only accept valid role IDs, and for that I need to check if a role with the ID that was given exists. Is there a way to do so? Here is my bit of code that is probably needed:

```js
execute(message, args) {
 if (!message.member.hasPermission('MANAGE_GUILD'))
  return message.channel.send(
   'You are missing the permissions to manage the server'
  );
 let guildID = message.guild.id;
 let warnedRole = args;
 if (!warnedRole) {
  return message.reply('invalid role ID');
 }
}
```

As you can see, I've tried doing it with an `if` condition, but I realised that it won't work as it would set the warned role to whatever you would type as an argument of the command (even some words or a number like 12). So is there a way to check if a role with the given ID (warnedRole) exists in the guild?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using `discord.js v12+`, you can try this:

```js
const role = message.guild.roles.cache.get(args[0]);

// if role does not exist
if (!role) {
  // ...
};
```